# Using \ifdefined for a definition inside \DeclareOption

Tags: packages, conditionals, definition

I'm checking for a command declared inside `\DeclareOption` but `\ifdefined` doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's a MWE:

```tex
% example23.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{example23}[2023/01/01 Example package]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{redcolor}{HTML}{ff0000}
\definecolor{bluecolor}{HTML}{0000ff}

\DeclareOption{red}{\gdef\red{1}}

\ifdefined\red
\newcommand{\mycolor}{redcolor}
\else
\newcommand{\mycolor}{bluecolor}
\fi

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[red]{example23}

\begin{document}
Test text \textcolor{\mycolor}{test}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Ouput]

When I import the package with `\usepackage[red]{example23}`, I expect the `\red` command to be defined and `\mycolor` be set to the red color. What am I doing wrong?

Please note that this a MWE and I am not actually using this to change the color.

Comment: the options are processed at \ProcessOptions.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot. :)